# parsing tfrecord with features constructed using tfds.features

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I prepared tfrecords using builder=tfds.builder(my_dataset, data_dir=data_dir) and builder.download_and_prepare(download_dir=data_dir).

The features underlying this dataset are defined in the DatasetInfo as follows

```
tfds.core.DatasetInfo(
    builder=self,
    description=_DESCRIPTION,
    features=tfds.features.FeaturesDict({
        # These are the features of your dataset like images, labels ...
        # 'image': tfds.features.Image(shape=(None, None, 3)),
        'image': tfds.features.Image(shape=(None,None,3)),
        'label': tfds.features.ClassLabel(num_classes=2),
    }),
    # If there's a common (input, target) tuple from the
    # features, specify them here. They'll be used if
    # `as_supervised=True` in `builder.as_dataset`.
    supervised_keys=('image', 'label'),  # Set to `None` to disable
    homepage='https://dataset-homepage/',
    citation=_CITATION,
)
```

I want to read a single tfrecord file generated through the builder.

I tried the following:

```
ds=tf.data.RecordDataset(tfrecord_files)
features=tfds.features.FeaturesDict({
        # These are the features of your dataset like images, labels ...
        # 'image': tfds.features.Image(shape=(None, None, 3)),
        'image': tfds.features.Image(shape=(None,None,3)),
        'label': tfds.features.ClassLabel(num_classes=2),
    })
for record in ds.take(1):
    parsed_record=tf.io.parse_single_example(record,features)
```

However, this throws the following error: ValueError: Unsupported Image Image(shape=(None, None, 3), dtype=tf.uint8)

How can I read a tfrecord file where the features are generated using tfds.features?

Thanks.